# ASP.NET MVC - How to maintain ModelState from a different controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, redirect, authentication

I have a HomeController with an Index action that shows the Index.aspx view.  It has a username/password login section.  When the user clicks the submit button, it POSTs to a Login action in the AccountController.

```
        <% Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post); %>
```

In that action, it tests for Username/Password validity and if invalid, sends the user back to the Login page with a message that the credentials were bad.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel Model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        User user = MembershipService.ValidateUser(Model.UserName, Model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            //Detail removed here
            FormsService.SignIn(user.ToString(), Model.RememberMe);
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");  // <-- Here is the problem.  ModelState is lost.
    }
```

But here's the problem: the ValidationSummary is always blank because we're losing the Model when we RedirectToAction.

So the question is: **How do I send the user to the action on a different controller without a Redirect?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said it's common to return the view if validation fails but as you are calling from your account controller you will want to specify the full path of your view

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx", model);
```

Or

It is also common to have a seperate login page and redirect to that page if the login fails.   Both pages will submit to the same login action.  Facebook does this for example.

Or

As you only want to display an error message

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { LoginAttempts = 1 });
```

then in your Index action read the `LoginAttempts` parameter and choose to display the error message accordingly.

Comment: Your option 1 was the easiest to implement and accomplished exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use `TempData` to save state between requests. Use special attributes for convenience as shown [here](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/21/the-big-boy-mvc-series-part-25-going-postal-actionfilters-moq-modelstate-oh-my/).

Few moments to mention:

- Don't return View directly from your POST-action, respect [Post-Redirect-Get](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Using-Post2c-Redirect2c-Get-Pattern.aspx) pattern.
- Don't overuse `TempData`. It's **only** supposed to save model state right before redirect and to retrieve it right after being redirected.

Comment: Post-Redirect-Get is only crucial when operation succeeds. When it fails it's common practice not to do the PRG pattern. Refreshing request doesn't harm the system in any way shape or form... In this particular case it fails.

Comment: Well, Robert, maybe it is somehow a matter of personal taste but I prefer PRG for whenever you have a chance of seeing a browser modal window asking you about reposting. I prefer more smooth and "history-friendly" UX. Maybe "Login" is somewhat special case but in regular forms I also prefer to only show form on that page with URL ending with "edit" not "update" (yes, I don't use the same action name for both).

Comment: How do you preserve model state errors for user, if you do PRG in case of failure?

Comment: @user6130, if I understand your question right then its exactly the point where `TempData` comes into play. I save the invalid ModelState there before redirecting to GET method and apply ModelState in that method after redirect (so I easily show the errors to user on initial form along with all the data entered by user). This is exaclty what TempData for. I use attributes for that so I don't have to pollute my Controller actions with those tedious repeating ModelState checks. You can even implement your own ITempDataProvider if you have specific deployment requirements. Makes sense?

Comment: @Vasilio I have seen this pattern and all the tempdata checks gets messier than the modelstate checks IMO, because at least ModelState has some structure to it and not just a loosely typed object in TempData.  Also you can get occasional bugs if tempdata didn't get consumed if the redirect failed due to some network fluke, and the user tries to refresh the page or hit enter in the URL bar to get a fresh empty form, but instead your code sees some tempdata[key] != null, and gives them a form with some data and error messages about some failure, when they weren't even trying to submit that form.

Answer (score 2):

### Three options

1. You could call the action directly, but the client side will not have its URL changed. So instead of calling `RedirectToAction` you could call the `Index()` method of the `HomeController` class directly.

   ```
   HomeController c = new HomeController();
   c.ViewData = this.ViewData;
   return c.Index(data);
   ```

   The one is a bit tricky. Maybe you will have to set other things as well apart from `ViewData` which is needed for `ModelState`.
2. You could as well use `TempData` dictionary and fill it with whatever data you want and use that.
3. The simplest one where you provide full path to the view

   ```
   return View("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx", data);
   ```

### A better suggestion used by *big players*

If we look at how other sites do this kind of scenario. Take for instance [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com) (As @David says [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) apparently does it the same). You can sign in from the `Home/Index` action (so to speak if it was developed using Asp.net MVC). But when login fails it displays a separate login page, that displays validation errors. In your case it would be `Account/SignIn`. Which would make sense and you could directly return its view with validation errors. When everything would be ok, you'd do it as you do it now. Redirect back to `Home/Index`.

Comment: Isn't the View(string, string, object) overload for view name, master page name and model not view name, controller name and model?

Comment: You're right. Let me adjust my answer. But I haven't checked whether it works or not. Do it and provide feedback when it doesn't work just yet.

Comment: I tried it. David was right.  Your revised answer also works, but doesn't maintain state unless you add a model after the viewname as some of the others have suggested.  +1 for the better suggestion used by big players, BTW. Excellent suggestion.

Comment: The difference between this and what "big players" do, is the above will not change the URL since it is not a redirect.  Thus the form submit from the browser after they correct the errors can potentially go to the wrong action.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could always do this

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.aspx", myModel);
```

It's not a real redirect, the clients url will still point to /login/ but at least you have your modalstate

Comment: As this is being called from the Login action of the Account controller this will return the Index view in the Views/Account folder and not the Index view from the Views/Home folder

Comment: You're right, didn't think of that. However that's easily solved. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
return View("Index", "Home", Model)
```

Comment: "Home" would be the name of the master page here, not the controller.